# Passing URL parameter to input text

Tags: php, html

I want to set the value from a URL parameter to a HTML form input text, like this:

```
 <div class="input_container">
           <div class="field_container">
           <?php $clave = $_GET['pu'];?>
              <input type="hidden" class="text" name="puntos_libres__id" id="puntos_libres_id" value="<?php echo $clave;?>" >
            </div>
          </div>
```

http://.../mispuntoslibres.php?pu=4

The form opens in a modal window, but the value for the input is not passed correctly to the action script. It always pass 0 as value.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps performing a pre-check for the `$_GET` Variable could  do. The  Snippet below demonstrates what is meant with that:

```
<?php   $clave = isset($_GET['pu']) ?  $_GET['pu'] : ""; /*TRY DUMPING: $clave*/ ?>
<?php   var_dump($clave); // JUST TO SEE ITS CONTENTS B4 IT GETS TO THE INPUT.   ?>

<div class="input_container">
       <div class="field_container">
            <input type  = "hidden" 
                   class = "text" 
                   name  = "puntos_libres__id" 
                   id    = "puntos_libres_id" 
                   value = "<?php echo $clave;?>" 
             />
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but echoing the get variable throws the expected value, 4 in this case.

Comment: @mvasco     Crazy; huh? And in fact your code is not so much different from this one. Perhaps, you could `var_dump()` the variable  directly to see what you get.....

Comment: this is the result: string(1) "4"

Comment: @mvasco And how does your URL look like? Could you, please, copy-paste your URL?

Comment: @mvasco   Perfect... Then the code is ABSOLUTELY RIGHT! Why? Because you just asked for `pu` which happens to be `4` as the URL says: `?pu=4`. But, what where you expecting otherwise?

Comment: I know @Poiz, the problem is that the input text doesn't show the value and then the value is not passed to the script that should insert the value in the database.

Comment: @mvasco   How are You opening the Modal? With JavaScript? So You have 2 Scripts, right? One gets the Variable & passes it over to the other which consumes it. How is your setup wired?